# User that already granted all permission is asked to re-sign such permissions and receive a security mail on each login?

Tags: authentication, email, security, permissions

I receive security mail

> "Security alert | *** was granted access to your Google Account| If you did not grant access, you should check this activity and secure your account."

each time I login with webapp. I see dialog windows with previously granted permissions and allow them again. What should developer do to clear this problem?

Expected result:
"Login with Google" for webapp with once granted permission does not ask for that permissions on each login and does not send security mail on each login